# How to check if a Perl scalar can be treated as a subroutine?

Tags: perl, reference, closures, operator-overloading

I have an API that originally took just a plain constant integer, but I am extending it so it can instead be computed when used by passing a subroutine reference instead. To keep backwards compatibility, I'm testing if it's a code reference:

```
'CODE' eq ref($var)
    ? $var->()
    : $var;
```

but I realized that excludes objects that act as subroutines. Something like this:

```
package Foo {
    sub new { bless {}, 'Foo' }
    use overload '&{}' => sub { sub { "Hello, world." } };
}
```

I could just try to call it inside an `eval` block, but then would have to carefully check `$@` to determine if it failed because it wasn't a subroutine reference (thus falling back to it being a simple scalar) vs. the called subroutine failed for some reason (error should be propagated).

In this case, of course, since the old value was a non-reference, I could just presume any reference is callable, but I'd like a general solution (as I've used this approach before when it used to be a hashref). Is there a simple and reliable way to test if a scalar is “executable”?

Comment: Using type-based polymorphism is inherently broken in Perl. That's why `keys($ref)` and smartmatching are failed experiments. For example, what if you have an object that overloaded both numification and `&{}`? You could even have a sub named `123`, a situation in which `123` becomes a valid reference to the sub.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check by attempting to dereference it, but not run it, as a subroutine.

```
my $is_code = ref $ref && do { local $@; eval { $ref = \&$ref; 1 } };
```

In this case you don't care what the error is, just whether one occurred. `\&$ref` is sufficient, but by assigning the result back to `$ref` you can avoid invoking the overload a second time when you call that coderef. Localizing `$@` is just for politeness.

As used in [my Autoload::AUTOCAN module](https://metacpan.org/source/Autoload::AUTOCAN#L48), with original credit to haarg.

Comment: Now, it returns false for things that can be treated as a subroutine, and it can return true for things that are integers. (If you want to support overloaded subification, you surely want to support overloaded numification)

Comment: @ikegami If you mean blessed refs that could also be used as integers, sure, there is nothing you can do about that when making this distinction. But I don't know what "could be treated as a subroutine" would fail the check.

Comment: Symbolic refs. .

Comment: @ikegami I'm going to say that accepting a symbolic ref is something no API should endeavor to do, or could sanely do.

Comment: No, what a Perl API shouldn't do is accept something that can be either an integer or sub.

Comment: in a perfect world, yes :)

Comment: @ysth That's just horrible (int-or-code interface) in any world, no? I'd say, more so in the real world.

Comment: It's actually quite fine if you don't go this far to DWIM, the problem is trying to guess what the user meant to pass. Accept only an unblessed coderef and treat everything else as an integer, you can use the simple ref check in the OP, don't give the user any expectation of other behavior. No complications, no ambiguity.